# ignore в TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, tortoise-svn

Подскажите, как настроить глобальное игнорирование файлов в TortoiseSVN. Сейчас я указываю список файлов для игнорирования, указываю использовать рекурсивно и он устанавливается для всех каталогов. Но если создаются новые каталоги, то на них нужно заново устанавливать правила. Есть способ раз и навсегда указать список для игнорирования?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пуск → Все программы → TortoiseSVN → Settings
General
Subversion → Global Ignore Pattern